# Recycler view scroll to position will not scroll properly, The top item is shown only half

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I m having a recycler view I implemented Scroll to position

```
final RecyclerView.SmoothScroller smoothScroller = new
            LinearSmoothScroller(getActivity()) {
                @Override
                protected int getVerticalSnapPreference() {
                    return LinearSmoothScroller.SNAP_TO_START;
                }
            };
int pos = recyclerViewAdapter.getKeyPosition(marker);
                if (pos >= 0 && pos <= recyclerViewAdapter.getItemCount()) {
                    smoothScroller.setTargetPosition(pos);
                    recyclerView.getLayoutManager().startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller);

                }
```

This is my layout looks like
[image]

Next, when I scrolling to position the top item shows its half portion
it look like this its overlapping
[image]

But I m trying to make it like this 
[image]

can you any help on this.

Comment: Post your layout xml..

Comment: post ur adapter plzz

Comment: Adapter is basic normal adapter onBind () getItemCount onBindVIewHolder() onCreateViewHolder, other than this nothing